# Spring boot DI using inject. Class not recognized

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm trying to get a Spring boot application running. I want to use DI for sure and I'm exploring the `javax.inject` annotations package. However, documentation on it is very scarce. This is what I have so far as a very simple set up

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Inject
    private IGreetingService greetingService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {

        return greetingService.greet();
    }
}

public class GreetingService implements IGreetingService {

    @Override
    public String greet(){
        DummyObject dummyObject = new DummyObject("valueOne", 10);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String dummyObjectJson = "";
        try{
            dummyObjectJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(dummyObject);
        }catch(IOException e){}

        return dummyObjectJson;
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Field greetingService in com.accenture.greetings.HelloController required a bean of type 'com.accenture.interfaces.IGreetingService' that could not be found.
```

- Should I really define my GreetingsService as a bean in XML? I'd rather not do that.
- What extra annotations/classes/contextmanagers do I need to make sure greetingsService is recognized and injected properly?

Comment: Put a `@Component` annotation above your class `GreetingService`.

Comment: Doesn't work. Same error. Have to mention that the service class is also in a different package

Comment: The service class must be in the same package or a package that is under the package that contains your Spring Boot application class. You can find lots of good tutorials here: https://spring.io/guides

Answer (score 2):

Put `@Service`on `GreetingService` and if it doesn't work then check for the project structure.

If your other package hierarchies are below your main app with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, you’re covered by the implicit Component Scan.

If there are beans/components in other packages that are not sub-packages of the main package, you should manually add them as `@ComponentScan`

Comment: The `@Service`, `@Component` and `@ComponentScan` are Spring boot provided annotations, right? What is the role of Spring boot if you use `javax.inject.Inject`?

Comment: Yes right, now answer of the second question is
Spring is not the only framework which provides dependency injection, in the future if you change your container and moves to another DI framework like Google Guice, you need to reconfigure your application.

You can potentially avoid that development effort by using standard annotations specified by JSR-330 

A bean declared to be auto-wired using @Inject will work in both Google Guice and Spring framework, and potentially any other DI container which supports JSR-330 annotations.